# Grabbing parent pages css with postMessage

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, postmessage

I have the following JavaScript which lies on a page within an iframe, and grabs the parent pages css to make the page have a seamless look to the rest of the page. I'm having an issue with it picking up the wrong styling however. How can I target specific tags(such as `h1`, h3`, etc to use on the page within the iframe?

```
var getFontFamily = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; j++){

            if(document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily){
                return document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily;
            }
        }
    }

    return 'not-found';
};

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var data = getFontFamily();

    window.frames[0].postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:3000');

    console.log('Message sent -->');
});
```

Current version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nzjfn6u4/11/)

This is the HTML that the css of the parent page needs to be applied to:

```
<div class="info">
            <div class="lead">Message Lead</div>
            <h2>Title</h2>

            <div class="ticker">
                <div class="ticker__also">Also</div>
                <ul class="ticker__list">
                    <li><a href="#">sub headline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub headline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub headline</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="extras">
        <div class="title">Extra info</div>
        <a class="link" href="http://www.url.tv" target="_blank">Link</a>

        <div class="share">
            <a class="twitter">Twitter</a>
            <a class="facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a class="email">E-mail</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get styles from elements directly via the `style` attribute and the `window.getComputedStyle` method. This is more accurate than just taking the first result that appears in the list of CSS rules (where you also just find selectors, not actual elements the style is applied to).

The [MDN page about the style attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) has some easy examples, for your purpose, it could be look like this.

```
var getFontFamily = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var cs = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
  return cs.fontFamily || '';
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying my code to pull by tag name with your code, but that isn't working. I'm also getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontFamily' of null`

I need to be able to have the style of the h2 tag or similar of the parent page, push to the child page within the iframe.

My updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nzjfn6u4/7/

Comment: Two problems in your fiddle:

1. You don't have any `h2` elements in your parent document, so no chance for `getComputedStyle()` to do anything :)

2. You're using `getElementsByTagName()`, here you have to keep in mind, that this returns an array of all found h2-headlines. So you might want something like `el[0]`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nzjfn6u4/9/

Comment: Still not working. As a better example, I need to be able to grab the font-family from the h1 or h2 header class of the parent page. So, for example on this one: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nzjfn6u4/10/. The "TEST" in the iframe should mimic the "Test headline..." on the parent page. There is other text that will be in the iframe, with different class names. I just need to be able to pull the primary font-family, and have it mimicked across the iframed page.

Comment: Works great in Firefox and Chrome. When I change the font for `.content__headline` it updates in the iframe as well and in the console I can see message sent and message recieved.

Comment: Yes, but the class to mimic won't always be `.content_headline`. This will be going on different websites, where the class for the headline font won't be the same.

Comment: You can change the element selector to whatever you need (tag, id, class). You even could add a parameter to the function, so you can request `getFontFamily('headline')` and `getFontFamily('some_paragraph')`